# Unable to Alloc Bytes - Large Scale Simulation in NS-2

Tags: tcl, simulation, ns2

I am running simulations using NS-2 for 5000 nodes and above.

I have encountered the following errors:

'`unable to alloc 32026 bytes`' [many such errors] and
'`bus error`'

I have used my code for up to 500 nodes and it worked fine. Now I am simulating for large networks. Has anyone encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of memory. That you're getting that message with such a small allocation indicates that you are *really* running out of memory; fixing this is not trivial.

One possibility that could be causing this is running too many other programs on the same system at once, and another possibility is that you have a memory leak. While Tcl itself is audited carefully for memory leaks, but I cannot talk about NS2 and your scripts could themselves be causing a “leak” by holding onto references to things for longer than they should. Sorting this out is a substantial amount of work.

Of course, you could take the good old-fashioned “throw more hardware at the problem” approach. Get a 64-bit build of Tcl and NS2 and run it on a system with, say, 16GB of memory. This option is a lot cheaper than it used to be as 64-bit hardware is going mainstream (at last!) but it isn't free…

Comment: This turns out to be a combined problem of limited hardware and large number of nodes (hence, possible memory leaks).

Further experiments work till 3500 nodes. As you said, it must be memory leak issue. Are you aware of any debugging tips to fix this, if possible?

But we are limited on hardware. I don't think I can use a system with 16GB memory!

Comment: Shame you can't upgrade memory; that's the easiest method as it just involves throwing money at the problem! Leak hunting is much more difficult; it might take me a while to come up with a good set of recommendations there (other than see if anything shows up in valgrind, bearing in mind that Tcl uses special memory allocators internally which can cause false positives…)

Comment: That's true but I work in a University. Hence not possible for me to increase the capacity of memory on servers!

Thank you for the insight. I shall use GDB and Valgrind to track leaks.